# Character of an irreducible representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

$H \leq G$, $[G : H] = 2$, $\theta$ is an irreducible representation of $G$, $\alpha$ is an irreducible representation of $H$. ( field is $\mathbb{C}$ ).

$\beta$ is a map such that $\beta(h) = \alpha(ghg^{-1}) \forall h \in H$ for some fixed $g \in G \backslash H$.

I managed to prove that $\beta$ is also an irreducible representation of $H$, but I’m struggling with finding its character. I know that $\chi_{\beta}(h) = \chi_{\alpha}(ghg^{-1}) = Tr(\alpha(ghg^{-1}))$, but since $\alpha$ is a homomorphism on $H$ it is not true that $Tr(\alpha(ghg^{-1})) = Tr(\alpha(h))$. Maybe now I need to utilise the fact that $H$ is normal in $G$ but I don’t know how to.

How do I continue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The outer automorphism "conjugation by $g$" on $H$ has the effect at worst of switching the classes.  That does happen, e.g., consider $S_3=C_3\rtimes C_2$.  So I don't think you can say much more than that.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks for your answer! 
I actually noticed that I said g is from G, but it is in fact from G\H. Not sure if it changes anything, just thought I’d keep you updated

Comment: What do you mean by "finding its character"? There is no general formula for the values of $\beta$ (other than the one you used to define $\beta$). It might happen that $\beta=\alpha$, but this depends on the group.

Answer (score 1):

This works quite generally, and you only need that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

For any $g \in G$ we have a conjugation automorphism
$$
c_g \colon H \rightarrow H \qquad c_g(h) \colon= g h g^{-1}.
$$
Therefore, given a representation
$$
\alpha \colon H \rightarrow \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}),
$$
we can obtain a new representation
$$
\beta := \alpha \circ c_g \colon H \rightarrow H \rightarrow \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})
$$
This is exactly the $\beta$ you are given in the question.

If $\chi$ is the character of $\alpha$, then the character $\psi$ of $\beta$ is simply
$$
\psi(h) = \chi(g h g^{-1}).
$$
You can show using the formula for the inner product of characters that
$$
(\chi, \chi) = (\psi, \psi),
$$
and therefore $\psi$ is irreducible whenever $\chi$ is.

Note that if we have $g \in H$ then because the character is a class function, we obtain that the characters $\chi$ and $\psi$ are the same, and thus the representations $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are isomorphic. In fact, the isomorphisms between the representations $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is given by the matrix $\alpha(g)$.

However for $g \in G \setminus H$ these characters can be different.